# i am unable to compile my selenium script in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

good day.
I wrote a little software using selenium and wxPython but when I am trying to compile it as a standalone executable I keep getting this error message.
I am making use of Python 2.7 in my windows 7 ultimate.
I have tried several methods to compile the script but I am still getting the same error message.
I don't just know where to start in other to fix this issue. I have also gone through the selenium folder in My system and I found the`get.Attribute.js`  in the particular folder.

This is the error message below:
`No such file or directory: 'selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js`

Comment: Please I really need assistance on this issue I am just a beginner in programming and Python is my first programming language.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Do the backslashes need escaped? Can you try either `selenium\webdriver\remote\getAttribute.js` or `selenium/webdriver/remote/getAttribute.js`?

Comment: Can you share your code block and the `Environment Details` please?

Comment: If you're on Windows OS then `'selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js` seem to be invalid absolute path.

Comment: Give me a minute to get the full error message

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blogstrike.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "selenium\webdriver\__init__.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.pyc", line 35, in <module>
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc", line 26, in <module>
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.pyc", line 43, in <module>                                                                            
  File "pkgutil.pyc", line 591, in get_data
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'`

Comment: This is the error message that I am getting

Comment: Is there any how I can fix the path ??

Comment: I am using Python 2.7   32bit and windows is 64bit

Comment: Try putting a full path, including drive letter, for example `"C:\\myfolder\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js"`. You have specified a relative path and it's clear that the interpreter is starting its search for the file from somewhere in the tree that is not what you expect.

Comment: That is my problem, I don't have a guide that will help me implement the path to it.

Comment: Or another way to compile this script and add the correct path in other to get the standalone executable.